# i need to find one element over class search, and only add a class to the first element that shows up

Tags: javascript

I know it sounds stupid, but I'm just learning HTML and CSS and my boss hit me with a JS problem and I have no clue.
I already tried googling a ton, but all I found, I also don't understand bc lack of JS knowledge.

I need to find a Picture Element with the class *.small floatfigure*, the element i need would be the first one of multiple with this class to show up, and the first and only one needs the class *.mgn* added.

I tried stuff like this, but like i mentioned i have no f***ing clue what I'm even doing

```js
var small floatfigure = { first: '.small floatfigure' };
      small floatfigure.forEach((e)=>{
           e.classList.add(".mgn");
          };      
______________________________________________________    

var floatfigure = document.getElementsByClassName('.small floatfigure');
var floatfigure = small floatfigure.firstChild;
small floatfigure.className += 'mgn';

______________________________________________________    

let aa = document.getElementsByClassName("small floatfigure");
aa.className = "small floatfigure";
aa.classList.add("mgn");

______________________________________________________    

var floatfigure = document.querySelectorAll(".small floatfigure");
console.log(floatfigure);
  if(!floatfigure.length==0){
      floatfigure.forFirst((f)=>{
           f.classList.add(".mgn");
      });
  };
```

pls pls pls help me

Comment: This is wrong syntax, `var small floatfigure = { first: '.small floatfigure' };`, please provide working example of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the first occurrence of an element in the DOM. The function accepts CSS selectors to search for the element you're looking for.

---

Edit: Just in case that there are multiple elements with both the classes `small` and `floatfigure`, add the `picture` element selector  to make your query more specific

---

```
const floatfigure = document.querySelector('picture.small.floatfigure');
floatfigure.classList.add('mgn');
```

Note that [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) searches for all elements that match the query and returns an *array-like* object which can be iterated over.

You can stay away from `document.getElementsByClassName`. That function was how we used to be able to find multiple elements, but have been replaced by, the more modern, `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.